# Whats wrong in this perl code ?

Tags: windows, perl, system

Im trying to run a set of commands in system command prompt using perl.

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;

print_prompt();


sub print_prompt {
print "What's your name?";
  system("G:\");
system("cd Documents and Settings/Administrator/eworkspace/Sample");
  print `ant`;

}
```

But this is throwing me following error

```
Bareword found where operator expected at execute.pl line 11, near "system("cd"
 (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 10)
String found where operator expected at execute.pl line 11, at end of line
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at execute.pl line 11, near "system("cd Documents "
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at execute.pl line 11.
```

how do I resolve this ? Whats is possibly wrong in this code? Do I need to indicate for the white spaces ?

Comment: Come on. Just look at the error message: There probably is a “runaway multiline `""`-string starting at line 10”. Look at the string on line 10. Ponder why it could span multiple lines. Even the syntax highlighting of your post is telling you!

Comment: you should refer [escape character](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two lines:

```
system("G:\");
system("cd Documents and Settings/Administrator/eworkspace/Sample");
```

are broken in a couple of ways. Firstly, the top one is broken in the way that other people have described before me. The `\` escapes the `"` so that it doesn't close the quoted string and the syntax of the rest of your file becomes broken.

But secondly, both of these lines are broken in a deeper way. They don't do what you think. Actually they both, effectively, do nothing. The `system` command invokes a new shell environment in which to run the command. The new environment inherits values from the parent environment (the one that is running your code). These values include the current directory. You then change the current directory in the new child environment. But when the `system` command finishes (which happens immediately) your new environment is destroyed. Your program continues to run in the original environment with the original current directory.

You should probably look at Perl's built-in [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
system("G:\");
```

1. This isn't a sensible command.
2. The backslash is escaping the `"`, so the the string actually is

   ```
   "G:\");
   system("
   ```

   or `qq{G:");\nsystem(}` with an alternate delimiter.

   After a string must come some form of operator, but `cd` isn't one.

The solution: never use backslashes as path seperators, they only cause problems. And remove the weird `G:\` command, what is it even supposed to do?

To include a literal backslash in a string, you have to escape it: `\\`.